# How To Get A Facebook API Key?

Tags: facebook, api, api-key

Okay, so I created a new account on Facebook but used the link that said 'Create a Page for a celebrity, band or business' I chose Brand or Product and signed up. Now it's absolutely impossible for me to get an API through my new Facebook account, there's no option to be seen to get the API key, in fact I spent half a day trying to figure out. I decided to log into my personal Facebook account and get an API key, managed to do it in 10 seconds flat, so why on earth is it so hard to get an API key if you've set up an account as a brand or product?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating and managing a Facebook app from a Business Account](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10805745/creating-and-managing-a-facebook-app-from-a-business-account)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to use a personal account to create applications on Facebook.  You'll also have to verify yourself as a developer using a mobile phone number or credit card.
These measures are in place so that facebook can identify the creator of applications as "real" people.

Comment: Couldn't have said it better myself.

Comment: That means alot to me Sir... Your answers are of the highest quality.  Thank you :D

Comment: :blush:  I'm just learning new things by trying to answer people's questions.  Many times I get it wrong.

Comment: In the meantime - OP has gone to sleep ;)

Comment: Thanks DMCS, at least I now know the reasoning behind it.

Answer (score 8):

For getting an Facebook API key in Facebook.Just go to facebook developers page and create an fb app and you will get your API key and secret.
Refer : [How to get facebook API Key easily via app](http://mytechshout.com/how-to-get-facebook-api-key/)

Hope its helpful.