# How to get an application key for Android - Facebook integration?

Tags: android, facebook, api

My Android developer is attempting to integrate with Facebook and was trying to get an Application Key but cannot do so.  Has the process changed?  Are there specific directions somewhere on how to accomplish this task?

Antonio

Comment: have a look at this link will help u surely  http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/scrumptious/authenticate/#step1

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821232/how-to-get-a-facebook-api-key), you will need to **create a Facebook Application** whereafter you will retrieve an Application Key (i.e. an API key).

Simply click on *+ Create New App* in the right uppermost corner of [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/apps), which will allow you to create an application whereafter you retieve both an App ID as well as an App Secret which you will need for your application.

Hope this helps.