# Tornado Facebook example not working

Tags: facebook, tornado

The page at 127.0.0.1:8888 is showing **Invalid App ID:ABC** when running the facebook.py provided in the demos of Tornado framework. How to fix??

Comment: Without the code it's hard to tell, but my guess is you need to register an application with [facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Demos/facebook.py on github gives the following instruction:

`python facebook.py --facebook_api_key=ABC --facebook_secret=XYZ`

Obviously you need to sign in to facebook and generate an API key for your application (instead of `ABC`/`XYZ`). See this question: [How To Get A Facebook API Key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821232/how-to-get-a-facebook-api-key)